# Regular expression pattern

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting

I am looking to create a regular expression to work with IIS URL rewrite rules.  I am looking for an expression to match the first two instance, but not the third.  I am looking to return the name of Folder2 whenever there isn't also a file name present on the end of the line.

```
Folder1/Folder2
Folder1/Folder2/
Folder1/Folder2/File.htm

^Folder1/([^/]*)/?$
```

I thought this expression would return the name of the second folder, with an optional /, when the second folder and/or slash is also the end of the line.  But it is only matching the first example and none of the slashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up having to use with IIS.

```
^Folder1/([^/^.]*)/?$
```

Answer (score 1):

try this sample of regex:

```
Folder1[\/]{1}([^\/]+)[\/]{0,1}[\n]
```

[Demo](http://regexr.com/3gof1)

Comment: I get a match on the first example only, it does not match the second example.

Comment: TY I see it working in your demo, but it fails in the IIS rewrite rule.